# what is the most efficient way to creating a dict with two lists?

Tags: python

I have two lists like

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] and
y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I have to create a dict from these two lists so that result is

```
{
 'a': 1,
 'b': 2,
 'c': 3,
 'd': 4
}
```

I do it using the following

```
dict(zip(x, y))
```

Is there a better and fast/efficient way of doing it?
I have to perform this operation on [m, b]illion of times and on different lists

Thank you

Comment: If you are using Python 2.X you can use `izip` instead of `zip` to return an iterator. Other than that your approach will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Praveen Gollakota's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/553995/praveen-gollakota) comment, the original method will work fine. In Python 2.x, you can also use the [izip](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) function in the `itertools` module. Either of these methods will work:

```
import itertools

x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
y = [1, 2, 3, 4]

method1 = dict(zip(x, y))
method2 = itertools.izip(x, y)
```

In Python 3.x, `zip` returns an iterator by default, so this method will work perfectly:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
y = [1, 2, 3, 4]

method1 = dict(zip(x, y))
```

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139075/187647) for why I'm answering an old question.